# Compiling code at runtime, loading into current appdomain but Type.GetType cant see it

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection, compiler-construction

Im compiling some code at runtime then loading the assembly into the current appdomain, however when i then try to do Type.GetType it cant find the type...

Here is how i compile the code...

```
public static Assembly CompileCode(string code)
    {
        Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false;

        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                string location = assembly.Location;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                {
                    compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(location);
                }
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException)
            {
                // this happens for dynamic assemblies, so just ignore it. 
            }
        } 
        CompilerResults results =
           compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                       error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
            }
            throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(results.CompiledAssembly.GetName());
            return results.CompiledAssembly;
        }
    }
```

This bit fails after getting the type from the compiled assembly just fine, it does not seem to be able to find it using Type.GetType....

```
Assembly assem = RuntimeCodeCompiler.CompileCode(code);
string typeName = 
      String.Format("Peverel.AppFramework.Web.GenCode.ObjectDataSourceProxy_{0}",
        safeTypeName);



Type t = assem.GetType(typeName); //This works just fine..
Type doesntWork = Type.GetType(t.AssemblyQualifiedName);
Type doesntWork2 = Type.GetType(t.Name);



....
```

Comment: I would expect after successfully creating the assembly and loading it into the app domain that Type.GetType would find types in the that assembly..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/22/SolvingTheAssemblyLoadContextProblem.aspx) nice bit of code that ensures no matter how you load your assembly it is always available from Type.GetType.

My class for compiling code into the current appdomain now looks like :

```
public static class RuntimeCodeCompiler
{
    private static volatile Dictionary<string, Assembly> cache = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
    private static object syncRoot = new object();
    static Dictionary<string, Assembly> assemblies = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
    static RuntimeCodeCompiler()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, e) =>
        {
            assemblies[e.LoadedAssembly.FullName] = e.LoadedAssembly;
        };
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Assembly assembly = null;
            assemblies.TryGetValue(e.Name, out assembly);
            return assembly;
        };

    }


    public static Assembly CompileCode(string code)
    {

        Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = false;



        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            try
            {
                string location = assembly.Location;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                {
                    compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(location);
                }
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException)
            {
                // this happens for dynamic assemblies, so just ignore it. 
            }
        } 


        CompilerResults results =
           compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
            foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                       error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
            }
            throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
        }
        else
        {

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(results.CompiledAssembly.GetName());
            return results.CompiledAssembly;
        }

    }

    public static Assembly CompileCodeOrGetFromCache(string code,  string key)
    {
        bool exists = cache.ContainsKey(key);

        if (!exists)
        {

            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                exists = cache.ContainsKey(key);

                if (!exists)
                {
                    cache.Add(key, CompileCode(code));
                }
            }
        }

        return cache[key];
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm researching this topic now and came across your code, @Richard, but I'm not quite sure how the cache mechanism works. Do you remember/can you explain? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You should read a bit more about assembly loading, type resolution, ... I don't know exactly why your code works at all, but I guess you have the following problem:

You compile the assembly and then you call AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load to load the assembly. But you do not return the assembly you have just loaded. You return the assembly from the compilation result. Now you have two instances of the same assembly and you have each type from that assembly twice. These pairs have the same names, but they are not the same types!

Comment: I can see the assembly loaded with 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

I can then see the type with
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[50].GetTypes()

However i think dynamicalyy loaded types cannot be found using Type.GetType

see http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/428836-reflection-type-gettype